# Error al crear base de datos en otro equipo con Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Realice un proyecto donde corro el code first en mi maquina y otra pero al descargar el proyecto en otra maquina me indica este error

> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file

Creo la bd directamente smss de sql server y me la ubica en:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

```
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="NominaContext" connectionString="Data Source=zeusServer;Initial Catalog=BD_PRUEBA;User ID=sa;Password=xxccvv;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

al tratar de el **update-database -verbose** me arroja ese error, me ubica el mdf en otra carpeta que no tiene acceso.

como puedo resolver esto?